# Use different IP in browser control C#

Tags: c#, .net, browser, proxy, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to develop an application, where user can load a proxy list and software should navigate to a page with different IP's. I'm using some registry settings to do that. But the problem is that when i try to change the IP address it remains the same, in "Internet Options" the IP has changed but on the web page which i'm navigating to, is still shown the IP I navigated first time with. Any solutions about that? or maybe, You have a better solution about this situation. Please suggest something. I tried "httprequest" some moments ago, but that was maddeningly unhelpful. Here's my code:

```
     private void BrowseProxy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
     {
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        ProxySrcTBX.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(ProxySrcTBX.Text))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                ProxyCount++;
            }
            r.Close();
        }

        try { Proxy = File.ReadAllLines(ProxySrcTBX.Text); }
        catch (Exception Exception) { MessageBox.Show(Exception.ToString()); }
    }

   private void SetProxy(string Proxy)
    {
        string key = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings";

        RegistryKey RegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(key, true);
        RegKey.SetValue("ProxyServer", Proxy);
        RegKey.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 1);
        RegKey.Close();

    }

  private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        SetProxy(Proxy[ProxyIndex]);
        label2.Text = Proxy[ProxyIndex];
        currentUri = new Uri("https://myip.ru");
        NavigateTo(currentUri);
    }
    public void NavigateTo(Uri url)
    {
        url = currentUri;
        webBrowser1.Navigate(url);
    }

   private void Dispose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetProxy("");
        string key = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings";
        RegistryKey RegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(key, true);
        RegKey.SetValue("ProxyEnable", 0);
        RegKey.Close();
        ProxyIndex++;
    }
```

Comment: Usually I use two IEs.  One for main page and 2nd for child page.  The list of IP address are on the main page and using one IE you will loose the list when moving to child pages.

Comment: But, what if i want to surf on one page with different IP addresses?

Comment: Then search contents of page.  Do not change URL,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understand correctly, you want to have a web browser control, programmatically change its the IP address from which it navigates and it makes it requests through?

This can be done via Interop with WinInet (one of the components that IE and the web browser control use under the covers)

Check out this [MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2011/04/26/how-to-set-the-proxy-for-the-webbrowser-control-in-net/) blog article

I will go ahead and post the code here so this post is self-contained.

```
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    namespace SetProxy
    {
        public static class WinInetInterop
        {
            public static string applicationName;

                [DllImport(“wininet.dll”, SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
                private static extern IntPtr InternetOpen(
                    string lpszAgent, int dwAccessType, string lpszProxyName,
                    string lpszProxyBypass, int dwFlags);

                [DllImport(“wininet.dll”, SetLastError = true)]
                [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
                private static extern bool InternetCloseHandle(IntPtr hInternet);

                [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
                private struct INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST
                {
                    public int Size;

                    // The connection to be set. NULL means LAN.
                    public System.IntPtr Connection;

                    public int OptionCount;
                    public int OptionError;

                    // List of INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTIONs.
                    public System.IntPtr pOptions;
                }
                private enum INTERNET_OPTION
                {
                    // Sets or retrieves an INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST structure that specifies
                    // a list of options for a particular connection.
                    INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION = 75,

                    // Notify the system that the registry settings have been changed so that
                    // it verifies the settings on the next call to InternetConnect.
                    INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED = 39,

                    // Causes the proxy data to be reread from the registry for a handle.
                    INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH = 37

                }

                private enum INTERNET_PER_CONN_OptionEnum
                {
                    INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS = 1,
                    INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER = 2,
                    INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_BYPASS = 3,
                    INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTOCONFIG_URL = 4,
                    INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTODISCOVERY_FLAGS = 5,
                    INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTOCONFIG_SECONDARY_URL = 6,
                    INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTOCONFIG_RELOAD_DELAY_MINS = 7,
                    INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTOCONFIG_LAST_DETECT_TIME = 8,
                    INTERNET_PER_CONN_AUTOCONFIG_LAST_DETECT_URL = 9,
                    INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS_UI = 10
                }
                private const int INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT = 1;  // direct to net
                private const int INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG = 0; // read registry
                /// <summary>
                /// Constants used in INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTON struct.
                /// </summary>
                private enum INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONN_FLAGS
                {
                    PROXY_TYPE_DIRECT = 0x00000001,   // direct to net
                    PROXY_TYPE_PROXY = 0x00000002,   // via named proxy
                    PROXY_TYPE_AUTO_PROXY_URL = 0x00000004,   // autoproxy URL
                    PROXY_TYPE_AUTO_DETECT = 0x00000008   // use autoproxy detection
                }

                /// <summary>
                /// Used in INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION.
                /// When create a instance of OptionUnion, only one filed will be used.
                /// The StructLayout and FieldOffset attributes could help to decrease the struct size.
                /// </summary>
                [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
                private struct INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_OptionUnion
                {
                    // A value in INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONN_FLAGS.
                    [FieldOffset(0)]
                    public int dwValue;
                    [FieldOffset(0)]
                    public System.IntPtr pszValue;
                    [FieldOffset(0)]
                    public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftValue;
                }

                [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
                private struct INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION
                {
                    // A value in INTERNET_PER_CONN_OptionEnum.
                    public int dwOption;
                    public INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_OptionUnion Value;
                }
                /// <summary>
                /// Sets an Internet option.
                /// </summary>
                [DllImport(“wininet.dll”, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
                private static extern bool InternetSetOption(
                    IntPtr hInternet,
                    INTERNET_OPTION dwOption,
                    IntPtr lpBuffer,
                    int lpdwBufferLength);

                /// <summary>
                /// Queries an Internet option on the specified handle. The Handle will be always 0.
                /// </summary>
                [DllImport(“wininet.dll”, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true,
                    EntryPoint = “InternetQueryOption”)]
                private extern static bool InternetQueryOptionList(
                    IntPtr Handle,
                    INTERNET_OPTION OptionFlag,
                    ref INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST OptionList,
                    ref int size);

                /// <summary>
                /// Set the proxy server for LAN connection.
                /// </summary>
                public static bool SetConnectionProxy(string proxyServer )
                {

                    IntPtr hInternet = InternetOpen(applicationName,INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, null, null, 0);

                    //// Create 3 options.
                    //INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION[] Options = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION[3];

                    // Create 2 options.
                    INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION[] Options = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION[2];

                    // Set PROXY flags.
                    Options[0] = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION();
                    Options[0].dwOption = (int)INTERNET_PER_CONN_OptionEnum.INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS;
                    Options[0].Value.dwValue = (int)INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONN_FLAGS.PROXY_TYPE_PROXY;

                    // Set proxy name.
                    Options[1] = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION();
                    Options[1].dwOption =
                        (int)INTERNET_PER_CONN_OptionEnum.INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER;
                    Options[1].Value.pszValue = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(proxyServer);

                    //// Set proxy bypass.
                    //Options[2] = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION();
                    //Options[2].dwOption =
                    //    (int)INTERNET_PER_CONN_OptionEnum.INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_BYPASS;
                    //Options[2].Value.pszValue = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(“local”);

                    //// Allocate a block of memory of the options.
                    //System.IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(Options[0])
                    //    + Marshal.SizeOf(Options[1]) + Marshal.SizeOf(Options[2]));

                    // Allocate a block of memory of the options.
                    System.IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(Options[0])
                        + Marshal.SizeOf(Options[1]));

                    System.IntPtr current = buffer;

                    // Marshal data from a managed object to an unmanaged block of memory.
                    for (int i = 0; i < Options.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Marshal.StructureToPtr(Options[i], current, false);
                        current = (System.IntPtr)((int)current + Marshal.SizeOf(Options[i]));
                    }

                    // Initialize a INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST instance.
                    INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST option_list = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST();

                    // Point to the allocated memory.
                    option_list.pOptions = buffer;

                    // Return the unmanaged size of an object in bytes.
                    option_list.Size = Marshal.SizeOf(option_list);

                    // IntPtr.Zero means LAN connection.
                    option_list.Connection = IntPtr.Zero;

                    option_list.OptionCount = Options.Length;
                    option_list.OptionError = 0;
                    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(option_list);

                    // Allocate memory for the INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST instance.
                    IntPtr intptrStruct = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(size);

                    // Marshal data from a managed object to an unmanaged block of memory.
                    Marshal.StructureToPtr(option_list, intptrStruct, true);

                    // Set internet settings.
                    bool bReturn = InternetSetOption(hInternet,
                        INTERNET_OPTION.INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION, intptrStruct, size);

                    // Free the allocated memory.
                    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(buffer);
                    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(intptrStruct);
                    InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);

                    // Throw an exception if this operation failed.
                    if (!bReturn)
                    {
                        throw new ApplicationException(” Set Internet Option Failed!”);
                    }

                    return bReturn;
                }



                /// <summary>
                /// Backup the current options for LAN connection.
                /// Make sure free the memory after restoration. 
                /// </summary>
                private static INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST GetSystemProxy()
                {

                    // Query following options. 
                    INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION[] Options = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION[3];

                    Options[0] = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION();
                    Options[0].dwOption = (int)INTERNET_PER_CONN_OptionEnum.INTERNET_PER_CONN_FLAGS;
                    Options[1] = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION();
                    Options[1].dwOption = (int)INTERNET_PER_CONN_OptionEnum.INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_SERVER;
                    Options[2] = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION();
                    Options[2].dwOption = (int)INTERNET_PER_CONN_OptionEnum.INTERNET_PER_CONN_PROXY_BYPASS;

                    // Allocate a block of memory of the options.
                    System.IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(Options[0])
                        + Marshal.SizeOf(Options[1]) + Marshal.SizeOf(Options[2]));

                    System.IntPtr current = (System.IntPtr)buffer;

                    // Marshal data from a managed object to an unmanaged block of memory.
                    for (int i = 0; i < Options.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Marshal.StructureToPtr(Options[i], current, false);
                        current = (System.IntPtr)((int)current + Marshal.SizeOf(Options[i]));
                    }

                    // Initialize a INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST instance.
                    INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST Request = new INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST();

                    // Point to the allocated memory.
                    Request.pOptions = buffer;

                    Request.Size = Marshal.SizeOf(Request);

                    // IntPtr.Zero means LAN connection.
                    Request.Connection = IntPtr.Zero;

                    Request.OptionCount = Options.Length;
                    Request.OptionError = 0;
                    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(Request);

                    // Query internet options. 
                    bool result = InternetQueryOptionList(IntPtr.Zero,
                        INTERNET_OPTION.INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION,
                        ref Request, ref size);
                    if (!result)
                    {
                        throw new ApplicationException(” Set Internet Option Failed! “);
                    }

                    return Request;
                }

                /// <summary>
                /// Restore the options for LAN connection.
                /// </summary>
                /// <param name=”request”></param>
                /// <returns></returns>
                public static bool RestoreSystemProxy()
                {

                    IntPtr hInternet = InternetOpen(applicationName, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, null, null, 0);

                    INTERNET_PER_CONN_OPTION_LIST request = GetSystemProxy();
                    int size = Marshal.SizeOf(request);

                    // Allocate memory. 
                    IntPtr intptrStruct = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(size);

                    // Convert structure to IntPtr 
                    Marshal.StructureToPtr(request, intptrStruct, true);

                    // Set internet options.
                    bool bReturn = InternetSetOption(hInternet,
                        INTERNET_OPTION.INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION,
                        intptrStruct, size);

                    // Free the allocated memory.
                    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(request.pOptions);
                    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(intptrStruct);

                    if (!bReturn)
                    {
                        throw new ApplicationException(” Set Internet Option Failed! “);
                    }

                    // Notify the system that the registry settings have been changed and cause
                    // the proxy data to be reread from the registry for a handle.
                    InternetSetOption(hInternet, INTERNET_OPTION.INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED,
                        IntPtr.Zero, 0);
                    InternetSetOption(hInternet, INTERNET_OPTION.INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH,
                        IntPtr.Zero, 0);

                    InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);

                    return bReturn;
                }

        }
    }
```

Comment: There is also a downloadable sample of another way to do it here : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSWebBrowserWithProxy-c8535715